# Java Nio absolute path to relative path

Tags: java, nio

I have a path that points to a file on disk, say: `C:\folder\dir\dir2\file.txt`. In the code, if an exception is thrown when working with this file, it will output the whole path. Ideally, it would be nice not to have the whole directory print out, rather something like `../../dir2/file.txt`.

It seems like I should be able to that with the [`java.nio.file relativize`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#relativize(java.nio.file.Path)) method, I'm just not sure how.

```
Path file; // C:\folder\dir\di2\file.txt
file.relativize(file.getParent());
```

I'm approaching this the wrong way I'm sure, just not positive how to accomplish what I'd like.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Get the current working directory

```
Path pwd = Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath();
```

and then `relativize` the target `Path`

```
Path relative = pwd.relativize(target);
```

Comment: i fail in same issue, but get the error that the format shlould be as:  [smallpath].relativize[longpath] -> file..getParent().relativize(file);